# MS Word Regex For Address

Tags: regex

I have to replace the document which contains multiple instances of following text 
" PROPERTY ADDRESS: **address varies for each document(contains alphabets & numbers)**, "

The search text always begins with "PROPERTY ADDRESS:" AND ENDS WITH "," after the address. I would want to replace this with blanks.

EX : The area PROPERTY ADDRESS: 1234 XYZ ROAD, COUNY, STATE, 12345-1234 , is good

I would want it to be replaced as "The area is good".

Any leads would help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Word, press Ctrl+H, check to option `More`: `Use wildcards`.
At `Find what:` = `The area * is good`
At `Replace with:` = `The area is good`
Then press `Replace` or `Replace All`!

Comment: What does * imply? How does it be for my example. Yes I tried with the one you said. No luck!

Comment: Don't write the `=` in `Find what:` and `Replace with:`. Just write `The area * is good`, and `The area is good` in them! You can read more at here: http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm

Comment: The thing is I just want to trim out the middle one or need to replace them with blanks in the address. I tried your suggestion , but it didn't work :(

Comment: Write to me, a paragraph example, then I will test for it!